# If $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$, is $f$ $1-1$ and onto or not?

Tags: functions

This question was asked in a masters entrance and I am unable to solve it.

> Question : Let $f: X\to X$ such that $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x \in X$. Then Prove that $f$ is $1-1$ and onto.

I have proved it to be $1-1$ but I don't know what reasoning I should use to prove it onto.

Kindly shed some light on this.

Comment: Take any $x \in X$ and prove that $x=f(y)$ for some $y$.

Comment: That $y$, by the way, might be written in terms of $f$ and/or $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that the function is onto, we have to show that for any $y\in X$, there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. But we already know that $f(f(y))=y$. Thus for any $y\in X$, we know that there is $x=f(y)\in X$, which satisfies $f(x)=y$.

To show the function is one-to-one, we need to show that for $x_1,x_2\in X$, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$. But $$f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies f(f(x_1))=f(f(x_2))\ \text{or}\ x_1=x_2$$